# How to use django custom decorator

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I have a lot of methods that require authorization. So instead of writting the same code over and over I wanna simplify it. As I understood I can't use [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) as it redirects to login page, which I don't have. (user logs in into system via dropdown menu included in all templates). I just wanna raise PermissionDenied without any redirecting.

```
get_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
       do things
    else:
       raise PermisionDenied
```

One solution is use a custom decorator:

```
def login_required_no_redirect(f):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied

    wrap.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = f.__name__
    return wrap
```

But it requires to pass a function inside. So I can't just place `@login_required_no_redirect()` above the method. It requires to pass some function as a parameter. Where do I get it? There're a lot of django decorators without parameters, how do I write the similar one?

Best regards,

Comment: I don't think you totally understand decorators. When you do `@login_required` above a function (note: no parentheses), you are effectively passing the function as an argument to the `login_required` decorator. The decorator you have written above can easily be applied just like any other one by using `@login_required_no_redirect` (without parentheses!) above the view function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django already has a [@permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) decorator for this.

> If the raise_exception parameter is given, the decorator will raise PermissionDenied, prompting the 403 (HTTP Forbidden) view instead of redirecting to the login page.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how could I solve the issue with custom decorator?